# What are the differences between equivalence, row equivalence and similarity in matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Two matrices being equivalent, row equivalent or similar are introduced in different linear Algebra text books. Each book has a different perspective and different level of difficulty. As a result, I get confused when trying to set apart each quality in terms of the definition, characteristics, ... Also, intuitively, I feel there are mathematical relationships between them.
May someone help with this?

Comment: See page 3 here: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/notes/linalg.pdf

Answer (score 6):

1. Similar matrices means that they represent the same linear operator. Two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are **similar** if there exists a non singular $n\times n$ matrix $P$ such that 
   $$A=P^{-1}BP.$$
2. Equivalents matrices means that they represent the same linear transformation. Two $m\times n$ matrices $E$ and $F$ are **equivalent** if there exists two non singular matrices $P$ of size $m\times m$ and $Q$ of size $n\times n$ such that:
   $$E=P^{-1}FQ.$$
3. Two $m\times n$ matrices $M$ and $N$ are **row equivalents** if one can be obtained from the other using only elementary row operations. This is equivalent to say that there exist a non sigular $m\times m$ matrix $S$ such that:
   $$M=SN.$$

Comment: +1 to this answer. However, I don't think this will help the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the file :). A linear operator makes a linear transformation, right? Is there a big difference between both? According to a text I'm reading, if two matrices represent the same linear operator but with different bases, then they are equivalent. Is this different from what you're saying?

Comment: Let $V$ be a vector space . Recall that a linear operator  on $V$ is a linear transformation $T$ from $V$ to itself, that is $T:V\longrightarrow V$.   If two matrices represent the same linear operator with respect to different basis, then they are similar matrices. If two matrices represent the same linear transformation $f:V\longrightarrow W$ w.r.t. different basis, then they are equivalent matrices.

Comment: Dear @Hector Blandin, It seems that your answer needs improvement and there is some confusion. To my understanding, Every transformation from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$ determines a certain operator $A$ that associates with every vector $x$ in $V$ a certain vector $y=Ax$ in $W$; in this case it's said that $A$ maps $V$ into $W$. $A$ is linear if it has the properties of linearity. A special case is when $A$ maps $V$ into itself, and it's said that $A$ is a linear operator in $V$ (on if $AV \equiv V$, i.e., the vectors $Ax (x \in V)$ fill out the whole space).

Comment: But in any case, it's also said that there is a linear transformation (mapping). Loosely speaking, the operation is called a "linear transformation (map)", and a linear operator is the one who does the transformation. By the way, please mention me so that I receive a notification. Thanks :)

Comment: You can call linear operator or linear transformation as you whish, that is not a problem. Look here to clarify (page 76 Definition at bottom of the page):   http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/anjp/textbook.pdf. The important thing is to understand that Some authors like Hoffman and Kunze use the name Linear Operator to specify that $T$ goes from $V$ to $V$ just to have a name for that particular case. If you choose the definition of Hoffman and kunze at page 76 is ok if not doesn't matter. I think the way you call mathematical objects in this case depends on your choice :)

Comment: Definition from page 76 Hoffman and Kunze says that Any linear operator $T$ on a vector space $V$ is obviously a linear transformation $T$ from $V$ to $V$ (This is the definition).